# How to filter the report generated by multiple values of a single field

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have built a report that generates data from a SharePoint list via Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder. I want to filter the report generation so that only items from the list with certain values of a certain field will display. Let me explain:

I have search extensively and have really confused myself. This is a report for the many projects in my team. They give updates on their project status and set a RAG status (Green, Amber, Red) weekly. This report pulls all this information together but I was it to only show projects that have an 'Amber' AND 'Red' status, exl. 'Green' RAG status.

*Image showing my current setup: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBre7.png)

I want help with the filter query that would be required. I don't want it as an selectable parameter.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm really confused! :)

Comment: Can't you just do this at the query level?  For example, in your SQL, just use something like `WHERE Overall_BRAGG_Status LIKE '%Amber%' OR Overall_BRAGG_Status LIKE '%Red%'`.  Easier to take care of it from the DB rather than deal with SSRS filters.

Comment: Can you change the Operator from LIKE to IN and place Red and Amber in the value field?  Or perhaps you could change your current value from *Red to *Red OR *Amber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like below.
In your case change Expression with field RAG status, whatever your field name is.

[image]

Comment: cool !! would be great if you could mark it as solved, would help others as well!!